# Separate a row of strings into separate rows

Tags: python, ruby, perl, shell, csv

```
Email,Division,Department
```

Expected output:

```
Email,Division,Department
```

Comment: So where are you stuck ? What does your current code look like ?

Comment: If this was a CSV, you would have three fields per record, not two. You have a TSV (tab-separated file).

Comment: Please do not tag the question with multiple languages.  You need to pick one that you want the answers written in.  Otherwise, this question is too broad.

Comment: @karthikr I don't have any code to solve this problem right now...

Comment: @Amadan This is a CSV file, not TSV, comma existed in field, e.g.tech,ux is in one field.

Comment: @iCodez Thanks for remind me, any programming language is good for me as long as it can resolve the problem.

Comment: Ok.. Lets start off this way: Pick a language, lets say Python - Open the CSV file, start reading the contents. - Then, you can split by a "DELIMITER". Edit this question with that code, and one of us can definitely help you

Comment: @user2908209 what people are telling you is that your question does not fit the Stack Overflow guidelines for a question.  Your question is likely to be removed because of what has been pointed out.  If you have a specific question the community can help you with you need to edit the question to match that.  This is not a code-on-request site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python Power Unleased :

```
import csv,sys
filename = 'a.csv'
with open(filename,'rb') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
try:
    for row in reader:
        if row[1].find(',') == -1:
            line = ','.join(row)
            print line
        else:
            for i in range(0,row[1].count(',')+1):
                line = row[0]+','+row[1].split(',')[i]+','+row[2].split(',')[i]
                print line
except csv.Error as e:
    sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your file is a real csv file.
But you can try this codes ,I think it works.

```
def convert(strs):
array=[]
if len(strs)==4:
    array.append({
        'left':strs[0],
        'right':strs[2]
    })
    array.append({
        'left':strs[1],
        'right':strs[3]
    })
else:
      array.append({
        'left':strs[0],
        'right':strs[1]
    })
return array

file='/Users/lidl/example.csv'
sumarray=[]
for line in open(file):
    line=",".join(line.split())# rebuild a str line with comma segmentation
    strs=line.split(",")
    sumarray=sumarray+convert(strs)

for item in sumarray:
    print(item['left']+" "+item['right'])
```

sorry for the codes bad format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick Ruby version:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# header
puts STDIN.gets

while line = STDIN.gets
        left, right = line.split

        left  = left.split(',')
        right = right.split(',')

        left.each_with_index{ |item, i|
                break unless right[i]
                puts item + "\t" + right[i]
        }
end
```

Test:

```
$ cat /tmp/test | /tmp/test.rb
Division    Department
tech    qa
ux      ui
tech    server
prod    prod
sales   sales
```

Comment: test.rb:10: private method `split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: err, while I was writing the code, you changed the input. The script was written for your old input.